# Trying to install mlpy on windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to install mlpy on windows.  When I try

```
easy_install mlpy
```

I get

```
No local packages of download links found for mlpy
```

and when I try to download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mlpy/files/mlpy%203.4.0/
There are only win32 versions available so when I run the file it cannot detect python 2.7 on my registry (I am using 64-bit python).  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks